# Date field is not getting saved in Django Admin

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-rest-framework

**models.py:**

```py
class Add_Timelog(models.Model):
    project=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    client=models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    Job=models.ManyToManyField(Add_Job)
    #Date = models.DateField(max_length=100 ,auto_now_add=True,editable=True)
    Date= models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)
    Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Date)
```

**settings.py:**

```py
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d')
```

When I posted a date in the api for the date field it is getting posted. But when I look that in the admin database it is showing as '%' in the date field, and if I tried to change the entry it is getting stored as 'undefined' and while saving the entries it is throwing an error as "enter a valid date". kindly help me to resolve this issue. Attached the screenshot of admin for your reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6kpn.png)

Answer (score 1):

The [**`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) expects an *iterable* of items, so:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d']
```

or with a singleton tuple:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d',)
```

Answer (score 0):

The tuple with only one value must have a trailing comma `,` as shown below:

```py
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d',)
             # A trailing comma ↑
```

In addition, the tuple with multiple values can omit a trailing comma `,` as shown below:

```py
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d', '%m-%Y-%d')
                        # No trailing comma ↑
```